# Loop to append text to variable labels

Tags: stata

I have a lot of variables that I have already labeled, but I want to include the units (thousands) in the label. Rather than adding `(000s)` manually to my long list of `label var` commands, is there a way to do it in a loop?

What I have so far only uses the name of the variable--is there another line that I can add before the loop starts that will extract and store the current label I have for the variable?

```
    foreach var of varlist A-Z{
        label var `var' "`var' (000s)"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is the following.

```
foreach var of varlist A-Z{
    local lbl : variable label `var'
    label var `var' `"`lbl' (000s)"'
}
```

In the `local` command the `:` introduces the use of a macro extended function, described in more detail in `help extended_fcn`.

In the `label` command note the use of the compound double quotes around the label. These are necessary should any of your labels include for example a single quote. See `help quotes` for a better explanation than I can give here.